# Problema con la Interfaz de Usuario en Talend Open Studio for Big Data: Ventana Reducida y No Muestra Términos

Tags: linux

Estoy experimentando un problema con **Talend Open Studio for Big Data (versión TOS_BD-20211109_1610-V8.0.1)** en un sistema **Linux**. Al abrir Talend, la interfaz de usuario aparece reducida a la mitad y no permite visualizar los términos y condiciones ni la configuración inicial, lo que me impide proceder con el uso del software.

Hasta ahora he intentado:

1. Modificar la configuración del archivo `TOS_BD-linux-gtk-x86_64.ini`, ajustando las opciones `-Xms` y `-Xmx` para asignar más memoria a la JVM.
2. Cambiar la resolución de mi pantalla y ajustar la escala de los elementos.
3. Verificar que no haya otras aplicaciones intensivas en recursos ejecutándose simultáneamente.
4. Buscar en línea soluciones relacionadas con problemas de escalado de visualización de gráficos en plataformas de alto DPI y Eclipse (la plataforma subyacente de Talend), pero no he encontrado una solución definitiva.

Mi sistema cuenta con 15 GB de RAM y he asignado 4 GB a Talend, la CPU es 154 y la resolución de pantalla es 1920 x 1080(16:9). Utilizo Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS como sistema operativo.

Este es el contenido actual de mi archivo `TOS_BD-linux-gtk-x86_64.ini`:

```
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx4096m
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
--add-opens
java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM


¿Alguien ha experimentado un problema similar o tiene sugerencias sobre cómo puedo resolver este problema de la interfaz de usuario reducida y no visible en Talend Open Studio for Big Data?

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda o sugerencia que puedan brindarme.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqoUe.png)

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Xs8.png
```